# Histograma 3D usando ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho dados de uma distribuição bidimensional, por exemplo, uniforme. Desejo fazer um histograma com esses dados. Tentei o pacote `plot3D`, mas não ficou muito legal.

```
teste = matrix(runif(100), ncol = 10) 

plot3D::hist3D(z = teste, bty = "g", phi = 15,  theta = -15,
                   xlab = "X1", ylab = "X2", zlab = "Relative frequency", main = "Teste",
                   col = NULL, border = "black", shade = 0.8, curtain = T, plot = T,
                   ticktype = "detailed", space = 0.15, d = 2, cex.axis = 1e-9, image = T, contour = T)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No seu caso eu faria um gráfico assim:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
teste %>% data.frame() %>%
  mutate(x = 1:10) %>%
  gather(y, z, -x) %>%
  mutate(y = y %>% gsub("X", "", .) %>% as.numeric()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nele você tem a mesma informação que no gráfico 3d (abaixo) porém (ao meu ver) é
muito mais fácil de enxergar. Na verdade, acho que nenhum gráfico em 3D ficaria bom.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Concordo que sua sugestão é melhor que o gráfico 3D. Por sinal, este tipo de gráfico se chama *heatmap*.